# about asp.net windows account

Tags: asp.net

when i want to access to a specific directory i catch an exception with this message:

> Error While Listing Directories:
>   Access to the path 'E:\Folder1' is
>   denied.

how can i correct this problem?

i add aspnet windows account to Administrators Group but still this problem accures...
please help... :)

Answer (score 2):

The E:\folder sounds like it is a mapped directory from another machine.  You'll have to give it access to the other machine to do so.

Comment: can you please say me how i can find it maped from what computer to this computer?

Comment: go to the command prompt on the server running the web app. Type: net use.  this will bring up a list of all the mapped drives and where they are mapped to.

Comment: this is the result of NET USE:
New connections will be remembered.

There are no entries in the list.

Comment: open up my computer and see where the E: drive is mapped.

Comment: i just can access to CMD and upload file to server. :)

Comment: oh...then you aren't accessing the command prompt on the server, that's why you aren't seeing the mapped drive.

Comment: I'm going to have to think about that.

Answer (score 1):

it is not good practice to add asp.net to administrators for security reasons. 
As i know  asp.net running NETWORK_SERVICE  so just add enough privileges for this user in properties of your folder

Answer (score 0):

give "Network Service" account the read access for folder 'E\Folder1'

Comment: these are accounts on my windows:Administrator,ASPNET,Guest,Internet, IUSR_FTP,IWAM_FTP,SUPPORT_388945a0 what account is network service